# How to decorate a vector and add a custom implementation of an iterator?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a custom iterator for a vector:

```
struct FriendsOnly {
  all: Vec<Person>
}
impl FriendsOnly {
  pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<Person> {
    // return an iterator of all Person where p.is_friend() returns true
  }
}
```

What is the canonical way in Rust to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you could do. Specify the return type in a more flexible way with impl Iterator.

```rs
use std::slice::Iter;
struct Person {
    pub name: String,
}

impl Person {
     pub fn is_friend(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

struct FriendsOnly {
    all: Vec<Person>,
}

impl FriendsOnly {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item= &Person> {
        self.all.iter().filter(|p| p.is_friend())
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `into_iter()` will copy data from `all` to a new vector, which is ineffective performance wise

Comment: It doesn't copy data because it yields references, and it doesn't return a vec but an iterator. However I m not sure to understand exactely what you expected though, your questions lacks some details about your constraints.

Comment: Do note that you don't need the final `.into_iter()`, `.filter(...)` already implements `Iterator<Item=&Person>`

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues oh yes thanks that was forgotten there...